# Problems with Full Text Search in Postgresql & .Net Core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, full-text-search, npgsql

I post this question because I dont found similar issue yet. I'm trying to ensure Full Text Search in .net core app, and according to [npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/full-text-search.html) documentation I have:
1) Model

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public long License { get; set; }
        public NpgsqlTsVector SearchVector { get; set; }
    }
```

2) DatabaseContext:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
       .HasIndex(p => p.SearchVector)
       .ForNpgsqlHasMethod("GIN");
```

3) Migrations:

```
 migrationBuilder.Sql(
            @"CREATE TRIGGER user_search_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
            ON ""Users"" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
            ts`enter code here`vector_update_trigger(""SearchVector"", 'pg_catalog.english', ""Name"", ""Surname"");");
```

Now, I'm trying use FTS in my app, where method Search gets from header 'phase' (string).

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromHeader] string phase)
    {
        NpgsqlTsQuery tsVestor = EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", phase);
        var response = Ok(_context.Users.Where(c => c.SearchVector.Matches(phase)).ToList());
        return response;
    }
```

I got:

NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlFullTextSearchDbFunctionsExtensions.ToTsQuery(DbFunctions _, string config, string query) in NpgsqlFullTextSearchDbFunctionsExtensions.cs

I also tried send by Header lexeme and comment line:

```
NpgsqlTsQuery tsVestor = EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", phase);
```

but i got: PostgresException: 42883: operator does not exist: tsvector @@ text

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT ---- :

Ok, I found answer on my question. Converting from string to NpgsqlTsQuery must be inside Matches method:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> SearchUsers([FromHeader] string phase)
    {
        return Ok(_context.Users.Where(c => c.SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery(phase))));
    }
```

Placing this convertion outside Matches method threw "NotSupportedException", and putting plain text as function argument threw 42883 Exeception.

Now, it's clear what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You should put the answer as an actual answer, it was hard for me to see that you had found the actual solution. I'll upvote it when you do.

Comment: Answer added :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @sonofaforester suggests, I put answer on my own question:

Converting from string to NpgsqlTsQuery must be inside Matches method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchUsers([FromHeader] string phase)
{
    return Ok(_context.Users.Where(c => c.SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery(phase))));
}
```

Placing this conversation outside Matches method threw "NotSupportedException", and putting plain text as function argument threw 42883 Exception.